# Does Raspberry Pi 3 supports ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: pi-3, ubuntu

I want to install ROS Indigo only, which supports only Ubuntu 14.04, and I have Raspberry Pi 3 kit. Does Raspberry Pi 3 support Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: There is no [official support](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi) from canonical for RPi 3 (yet). At least there is an unofficial Ubuntu 16.04 available. What about switching to [ROS Kinetic Kame](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic)?

Comment: Where are you planning to get Ubuntu 14.04 from? There has never been a Ubuntu 14.04 MATE release for the Pi. You could build your own, and if using recent firmware and kernel it should work.

Comment: As you might have noticed. Not hardware supports software but software has to support hardware. So you question should be: "Does Ubuntu 14.4 support Raspberry Pi 3?". Or "Is Raspberry Pi 3 supported by Ubuntu 14.4".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it would work but it would definitely be unstable or slow if it worked. There's another version of Ubuntu which works with the Raspberry Pi. It's called Ubuntu MATE, you can download it from here: https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/

There's also a little documentation for Ubuntu MATE on the Raspberry Pi on there: https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/

Comment: Mate works well. Just read the documents about updating. Don't use apt-get upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

An Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr) image is available for the Raspberry Pi 2, which combines the released 14.04 distribution with a PPA containing kernels and firmware which work on the Raspberry Pi 2.

*Warning ! This image, along with the one-off kernel it installs, is no longer maintained. Please use the 16.04 Xenial image instead. Warning !*

Ref.: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi

I would suggest that you go for "ROS Lunar Loggerhead" that supports:

- Ubuntu Xenial (16.04)
- Ubuntu Yakkety (16.10)
- Ubuntu Zesty (17.04)